# PHP button to execute SQL Query

Tags: php

I am trying to create a button, that after inserting the name of a user in my forum it deletes him from the data base (this goes in to the backoffi, for kicking people), this is the code i got:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';

echo '<h2>Command Center</h2>';
if($_SESSION['signed_in'] == false | $_SESSION['user_level'] != 1 )
{

    echo 'Desculpa, mas nao tens previlegios para aceder a esta pagina.';
}
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
    {

        echo '<form method="post" action="">
            Nome do user a apagar: <input type="text" name="user_name" /><br />     
            <input type="submit" value="KICK THE BASTARD" />
         </form>';
    }
    else
    {

        $sql = "DELETE FROM users(user_name)
           VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result)
        {
            echo 'Erro ao criar!' . mysql_error();
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Categoria adicionada com sucesso!.';
        }
    }


include 'footer.php';
?>
```

But i cant seem to get it to work, this is maybe a rather simple question but i can't get around it.

Comment: can you elaborate on "can't seem to get it to work"? what doesn't work, do you get any errors, what is the expected result where does it fail?

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear, i get this message on the localhost:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(user_name) VALUES('Pads')' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query:

```
 $sql = "DELETE FROM users 
         where user_name = 
       '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work and also protect you from the unautorised access (your code let's anyone delete users).

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';

echo '<h2>Command Center</h2>';
if($_SESSION['signed_in'] == false || $_SESSION['user_level'] != 1 )
{
    echo 'Desculpa, mas nao tens previlegios para aceder a esta pagina.';
    exit;
}


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
{

    echo '<form method="post" action="">
        Nome do user a apagar: <input type="text" name="user_name" /><br />     
        <input type="submit" value="KICK THE BASTARD" />
     </form>';
}
else
{

    $sql = "DELETE FROM users 
        WHERE user_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$result)
    {
        echo 'Erro ao criar!' . mysql_error();
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Categoria adicionada com sucesso!.';
    }
}


include 'footer.php';
?>
```